# centralize root node in svg

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have a graph designed in d3 js where in center the root node lies which is a rectangle and from that rectangle 4 other nodes are displayed by using lines to show them the links with it. I have a problem in aligning the rectangle in the center. How do i centralize it?

Here is my code

```js
var data = {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Person Name 1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Branch 4.1"
      }, {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      }
    ]
    }, {
      "name": "Person name 2",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Branch 4.1"
      }, {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      }
    ]
    }, {
      "name": "Person Name 3",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Branch 4.1"
      }, {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      }
    ]
    }, {
      "name": "Person Name 4",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Branch 4.1"
      }, {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      }
    ]
    }
    ]
    };
   

     const LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH = 13;
    
      let flagForChildren = false;
      var groups = [];
      data.children.forEach(d => {
        let a = [];
        if (d.children.length > 0) {
          flagForChildren = true;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < d.children.length; i += 2) {
          let b = d.children.slice(i, i + 2);
          if (b[0] && b[1]) {
            a.push(Object.assign(b[0], { children: [b[1]] }));
          } else {
            let child = b[0];
            if (i === 7) {
              child = Object.assign(child, { children: [{ name: "..." }] });
            }
            a.push(child);
          }
        }
        d.children = a;
        groups.push(d);
      });
    
      data.children = groups;
      let split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2);
      let rectangleHeight = 50;
      // Left data
      let leftData = {
        name: data.name,
        children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(0, split_index)))
      };
    
      // Right data
      let rightData = {
        name: data.name,
        children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
      };
      // Create d3 hierarchies
      let left = d3.hierarchy(leftData);
    
      // Render both trees
      drawTree(left, "left");
      drawTree(left, "right");

      // draw single tree
      function drawTree(root, pos) {
        let SWITCH_CONST = 1;
        if (pos === "left") {
          SWITCH_CONST = -1;
        }
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90 },
          width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
        let svg = d3
          .select("svg")
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
          .attr('view-box', '0 0 ' + (width + margin.right) + ' ' +             (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
          .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet")
          .style("margin-left", "-30px")
          .style("margin-top", "80px");
    
        // Shift the entire tree by half it's width
        let g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)");
        let deductWidthValue = flagForChildren ? 0 : width * 0.33;
        // Create new default tree layout
        let tree = d3
          .tree()
        
          .size([height - 50, SWITCH_CONST * (width - deductWidthValue) / 2])
          .separation(function(a, b) {
            return a.parent === b.parent ? 4 : 4.25;
          });
    
        tree(root);
    
        let nodes = root.descendants();
        let links = root.links();
        // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
        nodes[0].x = height / 2;
    
        // Create links
        let link = g
          .selectAll(".link")
          .data(links)
          .enter();
    
        link
          .append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("x1", function(d) {
            if (
              d.target.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent.parent
            ) {
              return 0;
            }
            return d.source.y + 100 / 2;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
            if (
              d.target.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent.parent
            ) {
              return 0;
            } else if (d.target.parent && d.target.parent.parent) {
              return d.target.y;
            }
            return d.target.y + 100 / 2;
          })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
            if (
              d.target.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent.parent
            ) {
              return 0;
            }
            return d.source.x + 50 / 2;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
            if (
              d.target.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent.parent
            ) {
              return 0;
            } else if (d.target.parent && d.target.parent.parent) {
              return d.target.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH / 2;
            }
            return d.target.x + 50 / 2;
          });
    
        //Rectangle width
    
        let node = g
          .selectAll(".node")
          .data(nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", function(d) {
            return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
          })
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
              if (d.parent.parent.parent) {
                return (
                  "translate(" +
                  d.parent.y +
                  "," +
                  (d.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 3) +
                  ")"
                );
              }
              return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
            }
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
          });
    
        node
          .append("rect")
          .attr("height", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 20 : rectangleHeight;
          })
          .attr("width", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleWidth(d);
          })
          .attr("rx", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5;
          })
          .attr("ry", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5;
          });
        node
          .append("text")
          .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 18 : 28;
          })
          .attr("dx", function(d, i) {
            if (!(d.parent && d.parent.parent)) {
              return 10;
            } else {
              return 20;
            }
          })
          .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? "Black" : "White";
          })
          .text(function(d) {
            let name = d.data.topic_name || d.data.name;
            return name;
          })
      }
    
      function rectangleWidth(d) {
        let dynamicLength = 6;
        if (d.data.topic_name) {
          dynamicLength = d.data.topic_name.length;
        } else if (d.data.name) {
          dynamicLength = d.data.name.length;
        }
        dynamicLength = dynamicLength < 5 ? 5 : dynamicLength;
        dynamicLength = dynamicLength > 30 ? 30 : dynamicLength;
        return 10 + dynamicLength * 8;
      }
```

```css
rect {
      fill: #149c10;
    }

    text {
      font: 14px sans-serif;
    }
    text:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .breadcrumb-chip {
      margin-top: 10px;
      background: #5dca5d !important;
      margin-left: -30px;
    }
    .breadcrumb-chip:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    line {
      fill: #149c10;
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: #149c10;
    }

    .breadcrumb-path {
      display: block;
      width: 1px;
      border: 0.5px solid #149c10;
      position: absolute;
      top: 90px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 10px;
    }

    .search-topic {
      margin: auto;
    }

    .btn-topic-search {
      min-height: 40px !important;
    }

    .breadcrumb-chip-container {
      width: 0px !important;
      margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
      
    </head>
    <body>
      <svg className='spider-graph-svg'>
      </svg>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The rectangle size is based on the length of text because sometime the text might be long and the text has to be seen inside rect but the root node is not aligned in the center properly. The topics vertical line should be in the middle of the root node . How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick  answer

```
 node.filter(d=>d.depth==0)
     .attr('transform',function(d){ 
      var width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      return `translate(${d.y+width/2},${d.x})`
    })
```

Check out snippet

```js
var data = {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Person Name 1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Branch 4.1"
      }, {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      }
    ]
    }, {
      "name": "Person name 2",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Branch 4.1"
      }, {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      }
    ]
    }, {
      "name": "Person Name 3",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Branch 4.1"
      }, {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      }
    ]
    }, {
      "name": "Person Name 4",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Branch 4.1"
      }, {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },{
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Branch 4.2"
      }
    ]
    }
    ]
    };
   

     const LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH = 13;
    
      let flagForChildren = false;
      var groups = [];
      data.children.forEach(d => {
        let a = [];
        if (d.children.length > 0) {
          flagForChildren = true;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < d.children.length; i += 2) {
          let b = d.children.slice(i, i + 2);
          if (b[0] && b[1]) {
            a.push(Object.assign(b[0], { children: [b[1]] }));
          } else {
            let child = b[0];
            if (i === 7) {
              child = Object.assign(child, { children: [{ name: "..." }] });
            }
            a.push(child);
          }
        }
        d.children = a;
        groups.push(d);
      });
    
      data.children = groups;
      let split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2);
      let rectangleHeight = 50;
      // Left data
      let leftData = {
        name: data.name,
        children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(0, split_index)))
      };
    
      // Right data
      let rightData = {
        name: data.name,
        children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
      };
      // Create d3 hierarchies
      let left = d3.hierarchy(leftData);
    
      // Render both trees
      drawTree(left, "left");
      drawTree(left, "right");

      // draw single tree
      function drawTree(root, pos) {
        let SWITCH_CONST = 1;
        if (pos === "left") {
          SWITCH_CONST = -1;
        }
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90 },
          width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
        let svg = d3
          .select("svg")
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
          .attr('view-box', '0 0 ' + (width + margin.right) + ' ' +             (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
          .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet")
          .style("margin-left", "-30px")
          .style("margin-top", "80px");
    
        // Shift the entire tree by half it's width
        let g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)");
        let deductWidthValue = flagForChildren ? 0 : width * 0.33;
        // Create new default tree layout
        let tree = d3
          .tree()
        
          .size([height - 50, SWITCH_CONST * (width - deductWidthValue) / 2])
          .separation(function(a, b) {
            return a.parent === b.parent ? 4 : 4.25;
          });
    
        tree(root);
    
        let nodes = root.descendants();
        let links = root.links();
        // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
        nodes[0].x = height / 2;
    
        // Create links
        let link = g
          .selectAll(".link")
          .data(links)
          .enter();
    
        link
          .append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("x1", function(d) {
            if (
              d.target.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent.parent
            ) {
              return 0;
            }
            return d.source.y + 100 / 2;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
            if (
              d.target.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent.parent
            ) {
              return 0;
            } else if (d.target.parent && d.target.parent.parent) {
              return d.target.y;
            }
            return d.target.y + 100 / 2;
          })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
            if (
              d.target.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent.parent
            ) {
              return 0;
            }
            return d.source.x + 50 / 2;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
            if (
              d.target.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent &&
              d.target.parent.parent.parent
            ) {
              return 0;
            } else if (d.target.parent && d.target.parent.parent) {
              return d.target.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH / 2;
            }
            return d.target.x + 50 / 2;
          });
    
        //Rectangle width
    
        let node = g
          .selectAll(".node")
          .data(nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", function(d) {
            return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
          })
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
              if (d.parent.parent.parent) {
                return (
                  "translate(" +
                  d.parent.y +
                  "," +
                  (d.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 3) +
                  ")"
                );
              }
              return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
            }
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
          });


    
        node
          .append("rect")
          .attr("height", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 20 : rectangleHeight;
          })
          .attr("width", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleWidth(d);
          })
          .attr("rx", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5;
          })
          .attr("ry", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5;
          });
        node
          .append("text")
          .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 18 : 28;
          })
          .attr("dx", function(d, i) {
            if (!(d.parent && d.parent.parent)) {
              return 10;
            } else {
              return 20;
            }
          })
          .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? "Black" : "White";
          })
          .text(function(d) {
            let name = d.data.topic_name || d.data.name;
            return name;
          })

node.filter(d=>d.depth==0)
 .attr('transform',function(d){ 
  var width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  return `translate(${d.y+width/2},${d.x})`
})
      }
    
      function rectangleWidth(d) {
        let dynamicLength = 6;
        if (d.data.topic_name) {
          dynamicLength = d.data.topic_name.length;
        } else if (d.data.name) {
          dynamicLength = d.data.name.length;
        }
        dynamicLength = dynamicLength < 5 ? 5 : dynamicLength;
        dynamicLength = dynamicLength > 30 ? 30 : dynamicLength;
        return 10 + dynamicLength * 8;
      }
```

```css
rect {
      fill: #149c10;
    }

    text {
      font: 14px sans-serif;
    }
    text:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .breadcrumb-chip {
      margin-top: 10px;
      background: #5dca5d !important;
      margin-left: -30px;
    }
    .breadcrumb-chip:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    line {
      fill: #149c10;
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: #149c10;
    }

    .breadcrumb-path {
      display: block;
      width: 1px;
      border: 0.5px solid #149c10;
      position: absolute;
      top: 90px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 10px;
    }

    .search-topic {
      margin: auto;
    }

    .btn-topic-search {
      min-height: 40px !important;
    }

    .breadcrumb-chip-container {
      width: 0px !important;
      margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
      
    </head>
    <body>
      <svg className='spider-graph-svg'>
      </svg>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if the text is very small, it wont be centralize